# ElasticSearch Query results in error "input_mismatch_exception" when executing LOWER()

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I am working on search functionality and I need to execute a simple query that checks if there is anything matching the search string converted to lowercase. In simpler terms, user searches "SiteName", and I query if there is anything matching "sitename".

However, I get an error when I use LOWER() function in the query.

This is what I tried:

```
POST /_sql?format=json
{
"query":"SELECT siteid, sitename FROM zones WHERE 
sitename LIKE  LOWER('SiteFirst')  ", "fetch_size" : 90 
}
```

and I get this error:

```
 {
 "error" : {
 "root_cause" : [
   {
     "type" : "parsing_exception",
     "reason" : "line 1:70: mismatched input 'LOWER' expecting {'?', 
 STRING}"
   }
  ],
  "type" : "parsing_exception",
"reason" : "line 1:70: mismatched input 'LOWER' expecting {'?', STRING}",
  "caused_by" : {
   "type" : "input_mismatch_exception",
    "reason" : null
    }
 },
  "status" : 400
}
```

This same query works without LOWER().

Any suggestions about how to fix this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `LOWER` is called [`LCASE`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/sql-functions-string.html#sql-functions-string-lcase) in ES SQL.

More importantly, [`LIKE` works only on exact fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-like-rlike-operators.html#sql-like-rlike-operators), plus [it's recommended to use `MATCH`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-like-rlike-operators.html#sql-like-prefer-full-text) instead of `LIKE`.

So try this:

```
POST /_sql?format=json
{
  "query": "SELECT siteid, sitename FROM zones WHERE MATCH(sitename, 'SiteFirst')",
  "fetch_size": 90
}
```